# What's the most efficient way to zip two nested list to a single level dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

for example:

```py
list1=['k1','k2','k3',['k4','k5',['k6','k7']]]
list2=['v1','v2','v3',['v4','v5',['v6','v7']]]
```

and I want to merge them to a dictionary like this:

```py
dict1={'k1':'v1','k2':'v2','k3':'v3','k4':'v4','k5':'v5','k6':'v6','k7':'v7'}
```

I have a way to do this, but I think it takes too much time:

```py
def mergeToDict(keyList, valueList):
    resultDict = {}
    for key, value in itertools.izip(keyList, valueList):
        if type(key) == list and type(value) == list:
            resultDict=dict(resultDict,**mergeToDict(key, value))
        elif type(key) != list and type(key) != dict and type(key) != tuple:
            resultDict[key] = value
    return resultDict
```

Is there any better ideas?

Comment: Your solution looks better than all of the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you need to flatten at all if you only have use cases like those you presented (nested lists but with the same shape). Here is an approach that at least on my machine is 2-3 times faster than yours (again only works with that constrain):

```
def appendDict(list1, list2, resultDict):
    for idx, val in enumerate(list1):
        if isinstance(val, list):       
            appendDict(val, list2[idx], resultDict)
        else:
            resultDict[val] = list2[idx]

list1=['k1','k2','k3',['k4','k5',['k6','k7']]]
list2=['v1','v2','v3',['v4','v5',['v6','v7']]]
resultDict = {}
appendDict(list1, list2, resultDict)
print resultDict

{'k3': 'v3', 'k2': 'v2', 'k1': 'v1', 'k7': 'v7', 'k6': 'v6', 'k5': 'v5', 'k4': 'v4'}
```

And a comparison of methods:

OP's method, on 10000 runs: 0.290050983429

Other proposed method, on 10000 runs: 0.580717086792

This method, on 10000 runs: 0.155267000198

Maybe not as elegant as the other solutions but performance seemed to be the main concern here.

Comment: The global variable can be just as well passed as paramter to the function, the idea is that it iterated only over one of the lists and does that only once.

Comment: That's really fast. Maybe you can pass in "resultDict" as a argument , that looks better.

Answer (score 5):

I'd use some kind of *flatten* function:

```
def flatten(it):
    if isinstance(it, str):
        yield it
        return
    try:
        for x in it:
            for y in flatten(x):
                yield y
    except TypeError:
        yield it
```

Now you can do

```
from itertools import izip
my_dict = dict(izip(flatten(list1), flatten(list2)))
```

I think this way is more general and more transparent for the reader.

Comment: I tested your code, but it seems that it runs two times slower than my code.

Comment: There's room for optimisation in the `flatten()` function -- for example avoiding exceptions by using `isinstance(it, collections.Iterable)` or `hasattr(it, "__iter__")`, or only descending into iterables of type `list`.  Most of these changes will harm either generality or readability to gain a small bit of performance.  If performance is really a problem, I doubt this is the place to optimise -- rather change how these lists are *created* in the first place.  In any case, *profile* to make sure your are optimising at the right place.

Answer (score 1):

With `flatten` defined as:

```
>>> def flatten(l):
...     r = []
...     for x in l:
...             if isinstance(x, list):
...                     r.extend(flatten(x))
...             else:
...                     r.append(x)
...     return r
```

`dict(zip(flatten(list1), flatten(list2)))` seems to be as fast as yours.  And it is much more convenient approach, as guys said.

Answer (score 0):

I like stacks and generator functions:

```
def flatten(seq, *seq_types):
    stack = [iter(seq)]
    while stack:
        for item in stack[-1]:
            if isinstance(item, seq_types):
                stack.append(iter(item))
                break
            else:
                yield item
        else:
            stack.pop()

keys = [0, 1, (2, 3, [4.])]
values = (5, 6, (7, "joe", [9]))
print dict(zip(flatten(keys, list, tuple), flatten(values, tuple, list)))
```

Result:

```
{0: 5, 1: 6, 2: 7, 3: 'joe', 4.0: 9}
```

Or, if you know for certain that the input lists have the same structure, this might also work:

```
def flatten(seq, *seq_types):
    seq = list(seq)
    for item in seq:
        if isinstance(item, seq_types):
            seq.extend(item)
        else:
            yield item
```

Beware that the order of items might change:

```
print list(flatten([1, 2, [3, 4, [5]]], list))
print list(flatten([1, 2, [[3, 4], 5]], list))
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 5, 3, 4]
```